# How do I archive/validate a Swift App that uses a framework in Xcode

Tags: xcode, validation, frameworks, cocoapods, archive

I have an App that uses Admod and Firebase from Google.  Since I am using Swift they want me to use frameworks when loading them from CocoaPods.  When I try to archive/validate the App I get the error:

`No suitable application records were found. Verify your bundle identifier 'org.cocoapods.GoogleToolboxForMac'`

What is the correct way to provision an app that uses someone else's frameworks so it can be uploaded to iTunes Connect?  I tried to find something in Apple's documentation but I haven't found anything.

**UPDate:**

I previously had answered my own question, since I had thought I had found a solution.  My reply was:

Problem Solved. Turns out I was using an App-ID that I am having Apple look into as being corrupt. I had already created a new App-ID to prove the one I want to use is not working and retried with that and it Validates. This required a lot of help from the Google Ads Mobile SDK team. Thanks.

So the correct answer is: **Now Incorrect**

You should not get this error unless you are using a Bundle-ID that is not already registered on iTunes Connect, but, you should never be able to create an archive that does not have a Bundle-ID that is not already registered on iTunes Connect. So this is caused by an abnormal situation.

**This is no longer true**

I used my new working project and got 4 whole builds out of it and into iTunes Connect.  In the process I was trying to clean up the mess caused by trying to solve this problem, like loosing my git history. I tried to modify my old App to get it to work and without modifying my new working project, But my new project started failing with the above error. I even used my time machine and went back to the directory as it was when I made the last build, but no help. So, any answers?

**Further Update:**

I pulled all the code related to Google Firebase and Admob out of the code and removed the cocoaPods and Archived/Validated and now I get the error:

```
You must supply a CFBundleIdentifer for this request.
```

Which is the error message I was getting with my other App-ID that tracked that App-ID in iTunesConnect.  This time it does not track the App-ID so it must be something in my project.  Will report what I find.

**UpDate:**

I think Apple has been modifying their code for validation at the same time I was trying different things.  At one point it told me I was using CFBundleSignature instead of CFBundlePackageType set to APP and I fixed this and got the code to validate.  Understand I am copying complete projects and renaming everything to debug this problem, so this must have come from the original program.  I ended up with a project that was renamed from my original but archived/validated but when I went to compile for Test I got errors that I debugged until I got lots of Mach-O link errors.  I decided to complete the loop and go back to my original code and try using the new Bundle-ID which points to the new App-ID, the one that works, and add all the knowledge I have learned.  But when I get it done I have an project that can test but does not validate.  The only difference is this project has the old identifier which has the same name as the suffix of the App-ID that has a bug.

Am I missing something?

**Final UpDate?**

On a whim I renamed the Scheme file to be the same as my Suffix to the Bundle-ID and I got my original Project to Validate! I have worked on this for over a month and you might not believe the astonishment I feel in this.
Back to Unit Test!

Answer (score 0):

I have come to the conclusion that the Identity of the App, the name at the far top of the right side Utilities window, has something to do with the way iTunes Connect validates the App.  This is the name in the left hand column of the Organizer window.  It is like it overrides the suffix of the Bundle-ID and since I can't use that Identifier because the associated App-ID is corrupt. Or the name of the Scheme.